# Using TPU on Google Colab Error_Cannot find any TPU cores in the system

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, google-cloud-tpu

I am trying to run [BERT model](https://github.com/google-research/bert#pre-trained-models) on Google Colab using TPU..

What is TPU_NAME exactly in:

```
!python run_classifier.py  \
.
.
.
--use_tpu=True \
--tpu_name=$TPU_NAME
```

I tried to define it as:

```
 TPU_NAME = os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR']
```

But, I faced the following error:

> INFO:tensorflow:Error recorded from training_loop: Cannot find any TPU
>   cores in the system. Please double check Tensorflow master address and
>   TPU worker(s). Available devices are
>   [_DeviceAttributes(/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, CPU,
>   268435456, 13626261043432226130),
>   _DeviceAttributes(/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0, XLA_CPU, 17179869184, 240953179956275984)].